# Protect original workbook after new workbook is created Excel 2010 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that is a template. The purpose of this template is to gather some customer information for billing and once some basic information is put onto it a new workbook is created and is editable for some fine tuning. Once the person is done editing the bill it is printed and saved onto a server.

Now, I am able to do everything I want perfectly fine, however I am having an issue when I try to protect the template after everything is copied to an editable workbook

How can I possibly re-protect the template while leaving the editable version unprotected? It sounds like it would be simple, but it is proving me otherwise.

I can provide any code if needed.

Comment: What have you tried?  If you are putting a password back on a sheet, it should be as simple as `Sheet1.Protect "password"`.  Same story if you want to protect the whole workbook again `ThisWorkbook.Protect "Password"`.  You just need to get references to the sheet or workbook.

Comment: I actually figured it out a couple hours ago. I was activating the wrong workbooks and doing the opposite of what was intended. I suppose I got tunnel vision from looking at it over and over again.